# Using ApplicationBuilder.jl to build standalone apps from Julia code

Tags: julia

I'm trying to learn how to use ApplicationBuilder.jl to build a standalone fully independent application for windows. for example, the following function could be the code for the app:

```
function Hello()
    println("Hello World")
end
```

then based on the ApplicationBuilder documentation the whole thing should be wrapped around a main function like this:

```
include("helloexe.jl") #address of the file containing the above Hello() function
Base.@ccallable function julia_main(ARGS::Vector{String})::Cint
    return Hello()
end
```

When I run the

```
using ApplicationBuilder
build_app_bundle("D:\\Julia\\my_julia_main.jl", appname="Hello")
```

it gives me the following error:

```
build_app_bundle("D:\\Julia\\my_julia_main.jl", appname="Hello")
[ Info: Building at path D:\Julia\builddir\Hello
[ Info: Copying resources:
[ Info: Copying libraries
ERROR: UndefVarError: build_executable not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] build_app_bundle(::String; resources::Array{String,1}, libraries::Array{String,1}, builddir::String, appname::String, create_installer::Bool) at C:\Users\Reza\.julia\packages\ApplicationBuilder\kMUzZ\src\bundle.jl:44
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[25]:1
```

What does 'build_executable not defined' mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR: I would advise to use [`PackageCompiler`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl) directly.** The [documentation](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/) is well written, and [this part](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/apps/) in particular explains how to build an application.

The skeleton of minimal application can be found [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl/tree/master/examples/MyApp). It boils down to [creating a package](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/creating-packages/) (named e.g. `Hello`), whose top-level module looks like this:

```
# file /path/to/Hello/src/Hello.jl
module Hello

function julia_main()
    try
        real_main()
    catch
        Base.invokelatest(Base.display_error, Base.catch_stack())
        return 1
    end
    return 0
end

function real_main()
    println("Hello World!")
end

end #module Hello
```

The compilation script then looks like:

```
using PackageCompiler
create_app("/path/to/Hello",         # this is the directory where Project.toml resides
           "/path/to/HelloCompiled") # target directory where you want your compiled app to be generated
```

---

The error you're getting comes from the fact that `ApplicationBuilder` depends on [`PackageCompiler`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl), which underwent a complete rewrite in the past few months.

`ApplicationBuilder` seems to have been written with `PackageCompiler` v0.6.3 in mind, but it does not set compatibility bounds and you probably installed the latest available `PackageCompiler` version on your system, whose API has changed and is not known by `ApplicationBuilder`.

You might want to file an issue with `ApplicationBuilder`, but in the meantime, if you really want to keep using it, you might want to try and downgrade `PackageCompiler` to an old version like 0.6.3.

Comment: I tried to downgrade the `PackageCompiler` but it gave me an error. I also tried using PackageCompiler itself but the documentation wasn't clear for me! `ApplicationBuilder` documentation was much easier to understand and work with!

Comment: I tried adding an example explaining how to use PackageCompiler to build an application. I'm not sure it's more clear than what's already in the documentation, but let's at least try...

Comment: As an aside, I think most package developers welcome issues saying things like "I tried using your package, but that part of the documentation was too hard to follow and I eventually did not manage to achieve what I wanted". Only new users can give such valuable insight, so if you have some time to devote to this, I would like to encourage you to submit issues explaining what got you confused... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think your explanation is much more clear! I submitted an issue for `ApplicationBuilder` error that I've got. I don't think if submitting an issue regarding not understanding documentation is something common, is it??

Comment: I exactly copy pasted your code and tried but after using create_app(). It says `ERROR: could not find project at "D:\\Julia\\Hello.jl"`. I also check the documentation and it says to first run Julia like with `julia -p --project` but this also didn't fix the problem and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Did you create a package, or simply a julia source file? You really need a package, that is a set of source files alongside with `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` files describing the software dependencies. The simplest way to generate a package is to use `Pkg.generate`, as explained [here](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/creating-packages/).

Comment: Thank you. The problem is solved. I wonder why there was no mention of the `Pkg.generate` in `PackageCompiler` documentation. I also submitted an issue about not having a step by step guide in `PackageCompiler` documentation and not being able to directly use it as my reference and ask them to improve their documentation.